# undefined method `pushes_path' for #<#<Class:0x007f85a15c6c90>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, routes

i'v been trying to resolve this error for the past 5 hours and I'm gonna burn my computer if I can't solve this.

undefined method `pushes_path' for #<#:0x007f859d605250> this is the error code I'm getting but i don't understand why.

this is my index.html.erb file inside of the interaction

```
<%= simple_form_for @push do |f| %>

  <%= f.input :payload, as: :text %>
  <%= f.input :segment, as: :radio_buttons %>
  <%= submit_tag "start the campaign" %>

<% end %>
```

and this is my interaction controller

```
class InteractionController < ApplicationController

def index

    @push =Push.new

end

end
```

Push is my table in the database and i'll get the inputs and write them in the database to use them for later one.

and this is my routes file

```
  devise_for :partners
  get 'home/index'
  get 'segmentation/index'
  get 'interaction/index'

root to: "home#index"
```

i really don't know why its looking for pushes_path, what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Try adding `resources :pushes` to your `routes.rb` file.

Comment: Please refrain from burning your computer - no-one likes innocent computers to be burnt!

Comment: I'll write an answer for you now sir!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**form_for**

The problem you have is that your [`form_for`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html) method is going to try and generate a route based off your `@path` object. And as such, if you don't have a path created for it, you'll receive the error you're getting:

> `:url`- The URL the form is to be submitted to. This may be represented
>   in the same way as values passed to url_for or link_to. So for example
>   you may use a named route directly. When the model is represented by a
>   string or symbol, as in the example above, if the :url option is not
>   specified, by default the form will be sent back to the current url
>   (We will describe below an alternative resource-oriented usage of
>   form_for in which the URL does not need to be specified explicitly).

The bottom line is that as Rails is [*object orientated*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming), its built around the assumption that you'll have *routes* set up to handle the creation of individual objects.

Every time you use `form_for`, Rails will attempt to construct your routes from your `object` -- so if you're trying to do the following, it will treat the routes as `photo_path` etc:

```
#app/views/pushes/new.html.erb
<%= form_for @push do |f| %>
   ...
<% end %>
```

--

**Fixes**

As `@mandeep` suggested, there are several fixes you can employ to get this to work:

Firstly, you can just create a route for your `push` objects:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :pushes
```

Secondly, as you're using a different controller, you'll want to do the following:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :interactions

#app/views/pushes/new.html.erb
<%= form_for @push, url: interaction_path do |f| %>
   ...
<% end %>
```

This will route your form submission to the `interactions` controller, rather than the `pushes` controller that you'll get by default!

---

**Objects**

Something to consider when creating Rails-based backends is the [object-orientated](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming) nature of the framework.

By virtue of being built on Ruby, Rails is centered on `objects` - a term for a *variable*, which basically encompasses much more than just a piece of data. Objects, in the case of Rails, are designed to give the application:

[image]

Once you understand this, the entire spectrum of Rails functionality becomes apparent. The trick is to realize that *everything* you do in Rails should be tied to an object. This goes for the *controllers* too:

[image]

--

Ever wondered why you call `resources` directive in your routes, for a controller? It's because you're creating a set of [*resourceful* routes](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#resource-routing-the-rails-default) based for it:

[image]

Do you see how it's all *object orientated*?

This gives you the ability to define the routes for specific controllers etc. The most important thing to note is how this will give you the ability to determine which routes / controller actions your requests should go

--

There's nothing wrong in using the controller setup as you have - the most important thing is to ensure you're able to define the custom URL argument, as to accommodate the non-object based structure

Comment: thank you for the long answer.Why it is assuming that its pushes controller?Because of the Push.new creation?

Comment: Yeah - it's all about Rails / Ruby being object orientated. I'll update my answer to explain

Answer (score 0):

In your index action you have

```
def index
  @push =Push.new
end
```

and your form has

```
<%= simple_form_for @push do |f| %>
```

so your form is looking for **/pushes with post verb or pushes_path** *and you don't have that route in your routes.rb file so to fix this you need to add this in routes.rb:*

```
resources :pushes
```

**Update:**

when you add `resources :push` rails basically [**creates seven different routes**](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#crud-verbs-and-actions) for you. One of which is

```
POST    /pushes pushes#create   create a new push
```

and if you look at the html generated by your form it would be something like:

```
<form action="/pushes" class="new_push" id="new_push" method="post">
  // your fields
</form>
```

*notice the action and verb so when you submit your form your routes are checked for them and **since you didn't define them in your routes you were getting this error***

> And how will i be able to use the params i m getting from this form with this new resource addition?

Your form will take you to pushes_controller create action so first of all you'll have to define them. You can access them simply by `params[:pushes]` in your controller action but since you want to create a new record so you'll have to permit those attributes, checkout [strong parameters](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#strong-parameters)

If you are using rails >= 4 then you can do

```
class PushesController < ApplicationController

  def create
    @push =Push.new(push_params)
    if @push.save
      redirect_to @push
    else
      render 'interaction/index'
    end
  end

  private
    def push_params
      params.require(:push).permit(:attributes)
    end
end
```

If you are using rails < 4 then instead of permitting these attributes(because strong parameters feature came from rails 4) you'll have to tell rails that these attributes are accessible by writing this in your pushes.rb

```
attr_accessible :attribute_name
```

> Why it is assuming that its pushes controller?Because of the Push.new creation?

That's because if you look at your index action `@push = Push.new` so @push contains a push object with nil values(as you have just initialized it) so this is where rails magic comes, rails automatically tries to figure out url of your form and since your @push is only an initialized variable so rails takes you to create action for it. For details you should checkout rails [`polymorphic urls`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing/PolymorphicRoutes.html) ***If you want your form to go to interaction_controller or some other url then you'll have to specify the url option for it***

```
<%= form_for @push, url: "your_url_for_custom_method" %>
  // other fields
<% end %>
```

And in the end you should really read [**`docs`**](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html)

Comment: so each time i'll create a new variable from my tables i ll need to put that as a resource?And how will i be able to use the params i m getting from this form with this new resource addition?

thnx so much tho it worked but i ll be more than happy if you answered to my questions as well :)

Comment: @railsnewbie no since you are creating a resource, in your case a push record, so you needed a route for that. You are using rails 4? will update my answer accordingly

Comment: @railsnewbie i was waiting for you to tell me which rails version you are using, anyways updated my answer :)

Comment: I  did all as you instructed but i m getting this error

 The action 'update' could not be found for PushesController do you have any ideas

Comment: another thing is, i every object successfully created but there is only timestamps of created at and updated at, it doesn't save it with the incoming attributes.Is it because of the given error ?

Comment: @railsnewbie for first error i think you are editing your record so you need to have update action inside pushes_controller, for second error can't really say until i have your code. You should ask another question with all the relevant code :)